# unlock encrypted external drive from commandline does not work

Tags: macos

I'm running 10.13.4 macos.
I created an encrypted hfs usb stick with the password `test`. After that I unmounted it and removed it from the Macbook. Then I plugged it in again and did NOT enter the password, so that the block devices appear in the device tree.

`diskutil cs list` delivers

```
+-- Logical Volume Group FDFF1CAB-A9AC-40E8-8251-FAC5C592296B
    =========================================================
    Name:         Ohne Titel
    Status:       Online
    Size:         3588186112 B (3.6 GB)
    Free Space:   14635008 B (14.6 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 0DB883F2-4AE3-4D13-AE97-5EF2E4EC28F8
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk4s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     3588186112 B (3.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 1865CD0A-BE9B-490A-8E02-A59498CAB371
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Locked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 53D7E549-5445-4509-8E0A-2FCB9DC59E4C
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  -none-
            Status:                Locked
            Size (Total):          3221225472 B (3.2 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Ohne Titel
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFSX
```

So I tried the following:

```
diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 53D7E549-5445-4509-8E0A-2FCB9DC59E4C
Passphrase:
Unable to register passphrase
```

It asks for the passphrase and I enter the correct one, but I get that error.

`diskutil list` shows:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.9 GB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Ohne Titel              3.6 GB     disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk4s3
```

so I tried:

`sudo hdiutil attach /dev/disk4s2`

which then opens the gui where I can type in my password, if I do that it works.
Which is nice but I want a command line only option. Any hints how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured this out I needed to use `sudo diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 53D7E549-5445-4509-8E0A-2FCB9DC59E4C` because `diskutil` seems to silently fail if it is not called with `root` privileges.